# Web and standalone app?

Tags: windows

I need to create an application that is primarily going to be about numbers and graphs, as well as UI controls to select information and input choices, filter lists, etc.

The application needs to be available as: 
a)  A web application so that a user can use the application via their browser 
b)  Downloadable, so that the user can use it without internet or browser - windows being the most important platform, followed by Mac OSX if possible.

Are there any recommendations for this?  Either Microsoft or open source solutions I am interested in considering.

I believe that the Unity 3d engine is capable of this, but I think that its focus on game development would get in the way too much for an application that is interested primarily in standard GUI controls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight supports [out of browser applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on Windows and on the [Mac](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/mtaulty/Silverlight-3-Running-Out-Of-Browser-Apps-on-the-Macintosh) so it can run in a browser and out of a browser in Windows or on the Mac.

There are graph controls available [freely from Microsoft](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) and there are other third party controls.